# Перемещение в начало строки TextField Flutter

Tags: flutter, jtextfield

```
TableCell(
child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
    child: TextField(

  controller: null,
)),
)
```

Я создаю колонку в таблице, и мне нужно, чтобы по заполнению (можно по нажатию <kbd>Enter</kbd>) оно показывало начало введённой строки, а не конец.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что решение работает следующим образом:

Дайте аргумент TextEditingController конструктору вашего текстового поля:

```dart
final myTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
final myTextField = TextField(..., controller: myTextEditingController);
```

При настройке нового текста внутри текстового поля используйте TextEditingController следующим образом:

```dart
myTextEditingController.value.copyWith(
  selection: TextSelection(
    baseOffset: 0,
    extentOffset: 0
  )
)
```

Это кажется необычайно сложным для достижения цели, но, похоже, это единственное решение проблемы обновления курсора в текстовых полях Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема с настройкой TextEditingController, и это сработало для меня.

```
controller.text = someString;
controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));
```

`TextSelection.fromPosition()` делает следующее (из документации):

> Создает свернутое выделение в заданной текстовой позиции. Свернутый
> выбор начинается и заканчивается с одинаковым смещением, что означает,
> что он содержит ноль символов, но вместо этого служит точкой вставки в
> тексте.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59525664/17040610)